# PHP & MySQL - Why is it not safe to rely on the system time settings?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, timezone

There are so many places where you can modify the time settings in a set up of Linux, Apache, PHP, and MySQL. I need to set everything to UTC in my server and I wondered why not just set the system time to UTC and all services just need to use the timezone "SYSTEM" as I did for MySQL.

However, a simple PHP warning made me doubt my decision. "It is not safe to reply on the system's timezone settings"

I have to questions, one may lead to another.

1. Why is it not safe to rely on the system time settings, specifically CentOS, in PHP, Apache, or MySQL?
2. What is the best way to unify the time settings from all services: Apache, PHP, and MySQL?

Comment: Setting the timezone explicitly in PHP means you would never have to change it again no matter which hosting you chose to deploy at. Also not all hostings allow you to change the system time settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not rely on system settings as they can be changed accidentally, as simple as that. Instead, specifying the desired timezone in `php.ini` makes sure somebody gave this a thought and selected the correct timezone that is going to be used (unless overridden by `ini_set`)
2. The best way is to specify the timezone you want in corresponding `ini` and `conf` files.

Moreover, if you have website now on US server and in few years you migrate to UK server, you want to copy your `conf` files as well and this assures that same timezone is used at all times.

Comment: Is there any case where someone install software in the system and it changes the time accidentally?

Comment: well, when multiple developers have access to the server, it can happen, and it did happen to me. I dont know about any software that would change this settings system-wide without user's approval, but I also see no reason why this should be impossible.